# Samsung Biometrics

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, biometrics

I've been looking around for some docs about using Samsung Facial Recognition, Iris, and Fingerprint scanner but all the information is just about Fingerprint. Can anyone point me to where I can find info about this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in this article: ["Using iris scans to secure mobile solutions"](https://seap.samsung.com/content/using-iris-scans-secure-mobile-solutions) and [that](https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/samsung-india-identity) SDK description. To get more information you should have:

1. SEAP Partner account.
2. Samsung Approval.